# Why didn't the sorting hat materialize the horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

Why didn't the sorting hat materialize the horcruxes? Had it materialized the horcruxes too along with the Sword of Gryffindor it would have saved harry and team a lot of time and also saved a lot of lives.

Comment: Why should it? It's not a magic materialise-everything device; it materialises the Sword of Gryffindor because that's a specific House heirloom which can be extracted by a 'true Gryffindor'.

Comment: for the same reason the fellowship of the ring didn't hitch a ride to mordor on the eagles

Comment: But the Sorting Hat was bewitched by all four of the founders of Hogwarts with brains and some amount of personality.

Comment: @MukundGandlur the sorting hat belonged to Griffindor. It was specially linked with him

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34005/4918 "How was the sword of Gryffindor pulled from the hat a second time?" and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/97574/4918 "When and by whom was Sword Of Gryffindor placed in Sorting Hat?"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Because one can't pull just anything out of the hat

> According to Dumbledore, speaking of the Sword of Gryffindor,
>
> Dumbledore reached across to Professor McGonagall’s desk, picked up
> the blood-stained silver sword, and handed it to Harry. Dully, Harry
> turned it over, the rubies blazing in the firelight. And then he saw
> the name engraved just below the hilt.
>
> *Godric Gryffindor*
>
> “Only a true Gryffindor could have pulled that out of the hat, Harry,”
> said Dumbledore simply.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*

In order to pull anything else out of the hat, one assumes some other condition might have to be met.

**However, both the sword and the Hat belonged to Gryffindor.**

> Twas Gryffindor who found the way,
>
> He whipped me off his head
>
> The founders put some brains in me
>
> So I could choose instead!
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*

It is likely that this is the cause of their connection, and that a true Ravenclaw (for example) could not pull the diadem out of the hat.