# Does the Sorting Hat produce any other magical artifacts like the Sword of Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter

The Sorting Hat will produce the Sword of Gryffindor for "worthy Gryffindors". Does it have similar artifacts for members of other houses? Or is it limited to that one artifact for that one house?

Comment: The sword in the hat was more of a one-time-thing in the Chamber of Secrets. The hat doesn't hold any artifacts within it.

Comment: It also appears (in the hat) to help Neville kill the snake near the end of the last book/movie. It's implied that it happens periodically - the Minister for Magic says at one point: "The sword may present itself to any worthy Gryffindor"

Comment: Damn! I guess i should go back and re-read the books.. i'm slipping :(

Comment: Note: the hat [used to be Gryffindor's hat](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97574/when-and-by-whom-was-sword-of-gryffindor-placed-in-sorting-hat?rq=1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Probably not

When the founders needed a way to select students for their houses after they were gone, Godric Gryffindor gave his hat (the sorting hat) and each founder put a bit of their brain in it. But the hat originally belonged to Godric Gryffindor. So its reasonable to presume that the hat would be able to produce the other relic which belonged to Gryffindor (the sword), to any "worthy" student. It is through this same logic that we can assume that hat will not produce Slytherin's locket or Hufflepuff's cup or Ravenclaw's diadem.