# Does one have to wear the Sorting Hat to pull the Sword of Gryffindor?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat, gryffindor

It seems very inconvenient. To get the sword in the situation of pressing need and danger, you first have to decide to wear someone's hat. What are the chances?

Was it the original design by Godric Gryffindor? Or can the Hat provide the sword, even if the person is just holding it?

Comment: The sword doesn't fall on your head. You need to reach in to get it...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How was the sword of Gryffindor pulled from the hat a second time?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/34005/how-was-the-sword-of-gryffindor-pulled-from-the-hat-a-second-time) specifically [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/139817/98028) : _"This sword was enchanted by Godric to appear **whenever a member of his house asks for help while wearing the Hat**. Twice, in the course of the Harry Potter series, the sword is transported from a temporary owner to aid a Gryffindor who needs a weapon."_

Comment: The Sorting Hat can read mind of a person who wears it. I guess that is the only way it can determine if someone realy needs the Sword.

Comment: @Valorum I believe the sword exactly fell on Harry's head and it was quite painful. I wonder if anyone who is getting the sword got to feel the same

Comment: @Jenayah Yes, I see it now, thank you.

Comment: @Demosthenes It totally make sense, like it only sense your presence when you're wearing it

Comment: Technically everybody DOES have to wear the Sorting Hat at least once to get the sword. The time they wore it and got sorted into Gryfindor